# Update Main UI With RichTextBox Data from BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, backgroundworker

I have a program that querys a bunch of WMI, Registry, and other data. It then formats the data into various RichTextBoxes highlighting errors from the data scanned on the remote computer.

I want to separate the different parts of the scan into different threads so it will complete in just a fraction of the time. It is working for the most part, but I don't know how to return a RichTextBox from a BackgroundWorker. It forces me to pass an object, and the object can only return plain text (AFAIK). It also tells me I can't update the RichTextBox from the thread.

After I have the BackgroundWorker query and format a RichTextBox, how do I get that data displayed on the main UI?

Comment: What type of information do you need from the BackgroundWorker? Text, color, font, etc? If you need all of these, make your own class to store the data, and return that as the result of the BackgroundWorker's DoWork function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DoWork` portion of your `BackgroundWorker` should assign the text to display in the `RichTextBox` control to `e.Result`. This does not have to be plain text... e.Result is an `object`. You don't want to touch any of the UI controls in this section of the BackgroundWorker... you're in a background thread, not the main UI thread.

The `RunWorkerCompleted` portion is executed next. The object you assigned in the DoWork section is available in `e.Result`. You're back in the main UI thread now, so cast the object to whatever type you need and assign it to your `RichTextBox` control.

Read [Threading in C#: BackgroundWorker by Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I'm able to return the results as an object, it just comes out in plain text. I will do some reading up on object casting, thanks.